# Add a line graph to an HTML webpage using the data from a real-time database in Firebase

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, graph, chart.js

I am doing a project that requires me to add a line graph in an html webpage. The data that will be displayed on my graph comes from a sensor that I connected to a real-time database in Firebase.

So what would be the easiest way for me to create such line graph?

I have tried using a simple line graph example directly from Chart.js and that worked. But again the data of the actual graph needs to be updated in real-time as well since it should refer to the data coming thru my real-time database...

Comment: Your question is rather vague. You can update the data using AJAX and a set interval that rebuilds the graph each minute or whatever you define, but again your question is vague.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What I mean by the line graph being updated in real-time, is that when the values from the firebase real-time database changes, the values should be reflected on the graph as well. But thanks for the response again. I'll look it up!

Comment: You need to buil;d it into the method that handles the db update or insert.